# Configurar visual estudio code para que solo me seleccione las aperturas de las etiquetas html

Tags: html, vscode

Tengo un problema con visual code, cada que doy clic en un `<li>`, por ejemplo, marca las etiquetas apertura y cierre.

Solo Necesito seleccionar las de apertura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con :

```
"html.mirrorCursorOnMatchingTag": false,
```

y me cuentas.

> Cuando se activa en etiquetas HTML, si tanto las etiquetas de inicio como las de finalización se "sincronizan", cambiar una también cambia la otra. Sin embargo, la función está deshabilitada de forma predeterminada, y usted ejecuta explícitamente el comando `On Type Rename Symbol` o establece la configuración `editor.renameOnType` en `true`.

[Documentación #1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87737)
[Documentación #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59394433/4717133)

Comment: graciasssss me ha servido

Comment: Bueno marca como respondida.